# relationships of topological and C* concepts in noncommutative topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory, operator-theory, noncommutative-geometry

According to wikipedia, noncommutative topology is " a term used for the relationship between topological and C*-algebraic concepts". Can somebody expand on this, give examples/theorems/results and references as to where I can learn more about this? Thanks

Comment: Gel'fand duality. K-theory of C* algebras. K-homology. The analytic surgery exact sequence.